# GPIO.event_detected not working though an edge is detected

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I am trying to count number of edges detected in a minute.
My code:

```
global future_time
future_time = (take_present_time()+pd.Timedelta('1m')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')        
global present_time
present_time = take_present_time().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
pulse_counter = 0
while present_time < future_time:#True:
    present_time = take_present_time().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
    # Count the pulses occuring within 1 minute
    print("Lets detect falling edge")
    GPIO.add_event_detect(read_pin,GPIO.FALLING)
    print(GPIO.event_detected(read_pin))
    if GPIO.event_detected(read_pin):
       pulse_counter +=1
```

Present output:

```
False # Meaning, no edge detected
```

There is an edge and it is changing. But I don't know why it is not getting detected by the `GPIO.event_detected`. How I know there is actually an edge? I tried same `GPIO.add_event_detect(read_pin,GPIO.FALLING, callback=do_this_when_edge_detected)`, it basically redirects this to a callback function, where I just count the pulses. The problem with this approach is, it never exits the `add_event_detect` function and it remains forever in that loop only. Hence, I am trying above approach, by which, I can count the pulses per minute.

Based on the @Joan's answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This task might be simpler and more reliable if you use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html).

```
import time
import pigpio

COUNT_GPIO=20

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
   exit()

cb = pi.callback(COUNT_GPIO)

while True:

   time.sleep(60)
   print(cb.tally()) # edges detected
   cb.reset_tally()  # reset count

cb.cancel()
pi.stop()
```

Note that the pigpio daemon must be running (`sudo pigpiod`) and pigpio uses Broadcom GPIO numbers.

Comment: I ran it but I am getting zeros only. Please, find my updated question.

Comment: Most likely is a mismatch between the software's idea of the GPIO you are using and yours.  Check with https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: Why have you removed the sleep?  You need to let it sleep for at least as long as one edge will take.

Comment: Sorry. My signal was changing so fast and I was just checking to see if it catches these. In all cases, with and without `sleep(60)`, it was just giving 0. On the other hand, my other code was incrementing at each edge detection.

Comment: Now I updated my question with `sleep(60)` response.

Comment: Unless it is switching at more than 200 thousand times a second `you have not told pigpio to use the correct GPIO`.